# Putting php file output in html div parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So this is my div that i require a php file for the "data-percent"

```
<div data-ui-jp="easyPieChart" class="easyPieChart" data-redraw='true' data-percent="1" data-ui-options="{
                  percent: 100,
                  lineWidth: 10,
                  trackColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
                  barColor: '#4BC0C0',
                  scaleColor: 'transparent',
                  size: 250,
                  scaleLength: 0,
                  lineCap: 'butt',
                  animate:{
                    duration:10,
                    enabled:true
                  }
                }">
```

But when i do  it just screws everything up, the file outputs a number from 0-100 so could i have an alternative of doing this

this is what i tried

```
data-percent=" <?php include('tlp.php');?>"
```

TLP.php file code:

```
http://pastebin.com/d3EPGT6j
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you tried?

Comment: show  your 'tlp.php' file code

Comment: That's fine  what you are including in data-percent , maybe you are getting more then 2digits after decimal so round up the value

Comment: Looks like your TLP.php is outputting HTML instead of only a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is very messy- for example I would wrap that files echo into a function that returns the value you are currently printing.

Why doesn't your approach work? Well, if I'm not mistaking, the way you do it inside quotation marks makes your compiler not recognise the tags you put there.

Instead, try to do this (not sure if it will work based on your tlp.php file tho)

```
<?php
echo "<div data-ui-jp=\"easyPieChart\" class=\"easyPieChart\" data-redraw='true' data-percent=" . include("tlp.php") . " data-ui-options=\"{
              percent: 100,
              lineWidth: 10,
              trackColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
              barColor: '#4BC0C0',
              scaleColor: 'transparent',
              size: 250,
              scaleLength: 0,
              lineCap: 'butt',
              animate:{
                duration:10,
                enabled:true
              }
            }\">";
?>
```

Comment: Could you include the compiled version of your html, so we can see what the data-percent is resolved to?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simplest method. You just include the php file before your html code and instead of echo variable in you tlp file assign value to variable. Than echo the variable on html div attributes.

```
<?php include('tlp.php');?>
<div data-ui-jp="easyPieChart" class="easyPieChart" data-redraw='true' data-percent="<?php echo $percentime;?>" data-ui-options="{
                  percent: 100,
                  lineWidth: 10,
                  trackColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
                  barColor: '#4BC0C0',
                  scaleColor: 'transparent',
                  size: 250,
                  scaleLength: 0,
                  lineCap: 'butt',
                  animate:{
                    duration:10,
                    enabled:true
                  }
                }">
```

In you tlp file remove echo $percentime; http://pastebin.com/XRUaTR9T

Comment: And what problem you are facing ?

Comment: everything is out of place and stacked, all the divs

Comment: I thing your issue in css or javascript. Add a screenshot of  your page.